# Reset infinite JavaFX RotateTransition

Tags: javafx, rotation, transition

**Problem**

In my application i use an infinite RotateTransition.

```
    Button btnRotating = new Button("I'm rotating");
    final RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), btnRotating);
    rt.setFromAngle(0);
    rt.setToAngle(180);
    rt.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    rt.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
```

When i stop this transition i want to reset the rotated node to its initial position.

```
rt.stop();
rt.getNode().setRotate(0);
```

Problem is that rt.stop() is asynchronous so the transition might not have stopped when i reset the rotation of the node. So occasionally the transition will overwrite my rotation reset.

**Unsuccessful solutions**

```
rt.onFinishedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    rt.getNode().setRotate(0);
});
```

Executing rt.getNode().setRotate(0) when the onFinishedProperty of the transition changes does not work as stopping the transition manually does not trigger the onFinishedProperty.

```
rt.statusProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if(newValue == Status.STOPPED){
        rt.getNode().setRotate(0);
    }
});
```

Listening for the statusProperty of the transition has the same problem as resetting the rotation manually. The status property gets set to STOPPED as soon as i call rt.stop() but it does not wait until the transition is terminated.

**Question**

So how can i safely reset my node to its initial position? How can i determine that the transition has really ended when i reset the node?
When i execute rt.getNode().setRotate(0) on the JavaFX application thread it seems to work reliably as my reset rotation gets queued after the last transition rotation. Is this the best solution? Should rt.stop() and rt.start also be executed on the FX thread?

Another thing i noticed is that in JavaDoc of the rt.stop() function it says: "Stops the animation and resets the play head to its initial position." So the play head gets reset but this reset is not transferred to the node as the transition is stopped. Is there a way to make use of that?

Answer (score 1):

```
btnRotating.setOnAction(event -> {
    if (rt.statusProperty().get() == Animation.Status.RUNNING){
        rt.stop();
        btnRotating.setRotate(0);
    }else{
        rt.playFromStart();
    }
});
```

you can stop animation from background thred by use this

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    rt.stop();
    btnRotating.setRotate(0);
});
```

Comment: Hi gearquicker, i think that is a solution that works fine as everything gets executed in the FX thread. Do you think it is possible to do stop the rotation and reset it without being in the fx thread?

Comment: If you need to do something in background thread use Platform.runLater(). In your example it would be Platform.runLater(() -> {rt.stop();btnRotating.setRotate(0);});